# Почему один блок div попадает в другой div?

Tags: php, html, css, веб-программирование

Есть морда сайта

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=utf-8"/>
<!-- Подключаем style.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 
<div style="width:465px;overflow:hidden;">
   <div style="height:400px;width:457px;overflow-y:scroll;">
     <?php include "forma.php" ?>
   </div>
</div>

<div>  
<button  type="sumbit" id="cnopka"  form="forms" action="index.php" name="submitForm" > Delete </button>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

В нем я вывожу form.php

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<?php


require_once 'login.php';


$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Что-то пошло не так MySQL: " . mysqli_error());

mysqli_query($db_server,"SET NAMES utf8");


mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database)
or die ("Что-то пошло не так: " . mysqli_error()); 


include 'script.js';


$query = "SELECT id,ip_addr,namepc,pass, passadm FROM vlc ORDER BY ip_addr ";  



$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
  
  echo '<table border="1">';
  echo '<thead>';
  echo '</thead>';
  echo '<tbody>';


?><form method="POST" id="forms" onsubmit="call(); return false" autocomplete="off"><?php

while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . long2ip ($data['ip_addr']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['namepc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['pass'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data['passadm'] . '</td>';
    echo "<td width='10px'><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value=". $data['id'] ."></td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}

?></form><?php


?>
```

Ну кнопка отправки формы. Проблема в том что кнопка почему то (по моей) логике не о отображается ниже формы, а когда я смотрю в мозиле то блок div кнопки перемещается в блок div формы. Почему это происходит ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы открыли тег - `echo '<tbody>';` а кто закрывать будет?

Comment: Или я дурак, или лыжи не едут. Это в каком у меня месте этот тег, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: ну вообще Ctrl+F в коде помогает. http://prntscr.com/gqolhu

Comment: Спасибо, увидел. Удалил '<tbody>' и в конце закрыл </table>. Не знаю на сколько правильно поступил, но все встало на свои места

Comment: ну можно было не удалять, просто добавить `<form></tbody></table>` и я бы посоветовал перенести ваше открытие таблицы ниже, после `form`. То так у вас сейчас открывается таблица, потом форма, потом колонки. По мне лучше всю таблицу обернуть формой - `<form><table>...</table></form>`